# boost serialization incompatibility between 1.74 and 1.83 with multi index container

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization, boost-multi-index

I am serializing a set of `content`s, indexed by multiple properties using `boost::multi_index_container`, and a `params` struct, into a binary archive which I want to deserialize latter. But the archive created using boost 1.74 is unreadable (Invalid or corrupted archive) when read using boost 1.83.

I have included an mre inside in the [git repo](https://github.com/neel/mre). Although it is a single small cpp file I made a repo to share it with the CMakeLists.txt and the Dockerfile. Following is my `content`

```
struct content{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    using angle_type = std::size_t;

    inline content(angle_type angle): _angle(angle) {}
    inline angle_type angle() const { return _angle; }
    void reset_angle_random(){
        static std::random_device dev;
        static std::mt19937 rng_angle(dev());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> angle_dist(0, 180);
        _angle = angle_dist(rng_angle);
    }
    void freeze(){
        // complicated deterministic business logic
        _angle = 0;
    }
    content frozen() const{
        mre::content copy(*this);
        copy.freeze();
        return copy;
    }

    static content generate(){
        static std::random_device  dev;
        static std::mt19937        rng(dev());
        std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist_length(-0.5f, 0.5f);

        mre::content content{0};
        content._length = dist_length(rng);
        content.reset_angle_random();
        return content;
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("length",  _length);
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("angle", _angle);
    }

    friend std::size_t hash_value(content const& c){
        std::size_t seed = 0;
        boost::hash_combine(seed, c._length);
        boost::hash_combine(seed, c._angle);
        return seed;
    }

    inline std::size_t hash() const { return boost::hash<mre::content>{}(*this); }
    inline std::size_t frozen_id() const { return frozen().hash(); }
    inline std::string id() const { return (boost::format("%1%~%2%-%3%") % frozen_id() % hash() % angle()).str(); }
    inline bool operator<(const content& other) const { return id() < other.id(); }
    private:
        double _length;
        angle_type _angle;

    private:
        content() = default;
};
```

The actual code I am working on is much larger and does not use the content struct mentioned here. The above mentioned content struct is a highly reduced version to make a minimal reproducible example. Following is my multi index container setup.

```
struct package{
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    struct tags{
        struct id{};
        struct content{};
        struct angle{};
        struct frozen{};
    };

    using container = boost::multi_index_container<
        mre::content,
        boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
            boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<mre::content>>,
            boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<tags::id>, boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<mre::content, std::string, &mre::content::id>>,
            boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<tags::content>, boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<mre::content, std::size_t, &mre::content::hash>>,
            boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<tags::angle>, boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<mre::content, mre::content::angle_type, &mre::content::angle>>,
            boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<tags::frozen>, boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<mre::content, std::size_t, &mre::content::frozen_id>>
        >
    >;

    inline explicit package(const mre::parameters& params): _loaded(false), _parameters(params) {}
    inline explicit package(): _loaded(false) {}
    void save(const std::string& filename) const;
    void load(const std::string& filename);
    inline std::size_t size() const { return _samples.size(); }
    inline bool loaded() const { return _loaded; }
    const mre::content& operator[](const std::string& id) const;
    const mre::parameters& params() const { return _parameters; }
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("samples", _samples);
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("params",  _parameters);
    }

    public:
        std::size_t generate(std::size_t contents, std::size_t angles);
    private:
        bool _loaded;
        container  _samples;
        mre::parameters _parameters;
};
```

I am also serializing a set of paremeters mentioned below.

```
struct parameters{
    std::size_t degree;
    std::size_t frame_size;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("degree",     degree);
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("frame_size", frame_size);
    }
};
```

Saving, loading and generating are done as following

```
void mre::package::save(const std::string& filename) const {
    std::ofstream stream(filename, std::ios::binary);
    try{
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive out(stream, boost::archive::no_tracking);
        std::cout << "serialization library version: " << out.get_library_version() << std::endl;
        out << *this;
    } catch(const std::exception& e){
        std::cout << "Error saving archive: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    stream.close();
}

void mre::package::load(const std::string& filename){
    std::ifstream stream(filename, std::ios::binary);
    try{
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive in(stream, boost::archive::no_tracking);
        std::cout << "serialization library version: " << in.get_library_version() << std::endl;
        in >> *this;
        _loaded = true;
    } catch(const std::exception& e){
        std::cout << "Error loading archive: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    stream.close();
}

std::size_t mre::package::generate(std::size_t contents, std::size_t angles){
    std::size_t count = 0;
    std::size_t v_content = 0;
    while(v_content++ < contents){
        mre::content x = mre::content::generate();
        std::size_t v_angle = 0;
        while(v_angle++ < angles){
            mre::content x_angle = x;
            x_angle.reset_angle_random(); // commenting out this line makes it work
            if (_samples.insert(x_angle).second)
                ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

It looks like a bug in boost multi index container. But I am unaware of any such existing bugs. I can reproduce the problem by compiling the [mre](https://github.com/neel/mre) in an Arch linux machine which has latest version of boost libraries. The mre also contains a docker target which compiles the same into an ubuntu 22.04 image in which default boost version is 1.74. The issue can be tested using the executable `mre` as following.

```
cd build
cmake .. && make
./mre pack archive_name 10 # to serialize 10 randomly generated contents and save to file named archive_name 
./mre unpack archive_name # to de-serialize
```

I order to test the incompatibility it can be compiled using docker.

```
make docker # compiles and generates a file named arc inside build/archives directory of the host machine
./mre unpack archives/arc # which throws exception
```

Comment: Is the buried comment "// commenting out this line makes it work"  relevant? Also your counts are off because there are unique indexes, but I'll ignore that

Comment: Yes, thanks for the edit. That could be the reason behind problem 2, inconsistent number of elements. I didn't expect that because the values are random. But that doesn't answer problem 1. That comment suggests that commenting out that line solves problem 1 sometimes, which means problem 1 has something to do with the keys of the multi index container.

Comment: @sehe Should I edit the question and remove the problem 2 since it looks irrelevant ?

Comment: That's up to you. Of course if with correct duplicate counting you still get deviations, it might still be related. My current state:blob:https://imgur.com/6ad1c9a8-da95-4d98-996b-03a4b89f1ba5 so let's get this party started :)

Comment: Actually I was puzzled for several days for problem 1. And while reproducing it using minimal example, problem 2 occurred in mre. So, I thought it might be related. But I think that is because I forgot to put the checks. But problem 1 is the actual problem. So, mentioning problem 2 might deviate the readers from the actual issue. So, I am editing it and removing problem 2. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Boost.MultiIndex's author here. Can you please verify if the exception is thrown from here?
https://github.com/boostorg/multi_index/blob/develop/include/boost/multi_index/detail/ord_index_impl.hpp#L1510

Comment: @JoaquínMLópezMuñoz Yes. Please find the backtrace (#8) here https://gist.github.com/neel/7dc54717ca034c545084dcf4acb3a178.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this a long time, I couldn't see it. However, by [fixing the seeds](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbd6f8005ed3a5a4) and verifying that we get deterministic data, I noticed that the results were "identical" but for the order.

I noticed the default index already relies on the hash indirectly, multiple times:

```
                      ┌─────────────────────┐
                      │                     │
                  ┌−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−┐       │
                  ╎      both       ╎       │
                  ╎                 ╎       ▼
┌───────────┐     ╎ ┌─────────────┐ ╎     ┌────────┐     ┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────────────┐
│ operator< │ ──▶ ╎ │    id()     │ ╎ ──▶ │ hash() │ ──▶ │ boost::hash<> │ ──▶ │ boost::hash_combine() │
└───────────┘     ╎ └─────────────┘ ╎     └────────┘     └───────────────┘     └───────────────────────┘
                  ╎   │             ╎
                  ╎   │             ╎
                  ╎   ▼             ╎
                  ╎ ┌─────────────┐ ╎
                  ╎ │ frozen_id() │ ╎
                  ╎ └─────────────┘ ╎
                  ╎                 ╎
                  └−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−┘
```

Since the first index is actually also unique, and the only constituent parts are hashes and the angle, this might cause different uniqueness across version of Boost ContainerHash.

Boost `hash_combine` does not guarantee stability or portability. In fact, most common hash functions don't, e.g. [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash):

> The actual hash functions are **implementation-dependent** and are not required to fulfill any other quality criteria except those specified above

In fact persisting information depending on deterministic hash is a logic error anywhere, unless you're only re-reading the same information in the same process, because

> Hash functions are only required to produce the same result for the same input **within a single execution of a program**; this allows salted hashes that prevent collision denial-of-service attacks.

Specifically, `hash_combine` has received many changes between 1.74 and 1.83. You should rethink your indexes. In fact, I would consider it a smell that a hash depending on non-unique hashes is being used as the key (`identity`) to a unique index.

### Fixing?

To avoid violating the total ordering contract that the index expects (it's basically like you edited the key fields by "editing" the hash function), I'd expect the hash to be something like

```
inline constexpr std::tuple<double, angle_type> key() const { return {_length, _angle}; }
friend std::size_t hash_value(content const& c) { return boost::hash_value(c.key()); }
```

And then perhaps something more like:

```
    using key_type = std::tuple<double, angle_type>;
    key_type      key() const                  { return {_length, _angle}; }
    key_type      frozen_key() const           { return frozen().key(); }

    friend size_t hash_value(content const& c) { return boost::hash_value(c.key()); }
    size_t        hash() const                 { return hash_value(*this); }

    auto idkey() const                         { return std::tuple(frozen_key(), key(), angle()); }
    std::string id() const                     { return fmt::format("{}", idkey()); }
    bool operator<(content const& other) const { return idkey() < other.idkey(); }
```

Where I substituted libfmt for Boost Format, because it can directly format tuples without me doing the work :)

Basically, I'd not throw away the information, which seemed like code smell anyways, but also caused the indexes to rely on non-deterministic functions.

Here's my motivating code listing, complete with the tweaks to optionally use a fixed seed:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42fb40af102c7f11)**

```cpp
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/container_hash/hash.hpp>
#include <boost/core/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/utility.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <cstdint>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>

#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

static constexpr boost::archive::archive_flags FLAGS = boost::archive::archive_flags::no_tracking; //  {};

#if 1
    using IA = boost::archive::binary_iarchive;
    using OA = boost::archive::binary_oarchive;
#else
    using IA = boost::archive::text_iarchive;
    using OA = boost::archive::text_oarchive;
#endif

namespace mre {

    struct content {
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        using angle_type = std::size_t;

        inline content(angle_type angle) : _angle(angle) {}
        inline angle_type angle() const { return _angle; }

        void reset_angle_random(size_t seed) {
            static std::mt19937             rng_angle(seed);
            std::uniform_int_distribution<> angle_dist(0, 180);
            _angle = angle_dist(rng_angle);
        }

        void freeze() {
            // complicated deterministic business logic
            _angle = 0;
        }
        content frozen() const {
            mre::content copy(*this);
            copy.freeze();
            return copy;
        }

        static content generate() {
            return generate(std::random_device{}());
        }
        static content generate(size_t seed) {
            static std::mt19937              rng(seed);
            std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist_length(-0.5f, 0.5f);

            mre::content content{0};
            content._length = dist_length(rng);
            content.reset_angle_random(rng());
            return content;
        }

        template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned) {
            ar& boost::serialization::make_nvp("length", _length);
            ar& boost::serialization::make_nvp("angle", _angle);
        }

        using key_type = std::tuple<double, angle_type>;
        key_type      key() const                  { return {_length, _angle}; }
        key_type      frozen_key() const           { return frozen().key(); }

        friend size_t hash_value(content const& c) { return boost::hash_value(c.key()); }
        size_t        hash() const                 { return hash_value(*this); }

        auto idkey() const                         { return std::tuple(frozen_key(), key(), angle()); }
        std::string id() const                     { return fmt::format("{}", idkey()); }
        bool operator<(content const& other) const { return idkey() < other.idkey(); }

      private:
        double     _length;
        angle_type _angle;

      private:
        content() = default;
    };

    struct parameters {
        std::size_t degree;
        std::size_t frame_size;

        template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned) {
            ar& boost::serialization::make_nvp("degree", degree);
            ar& boost::serialization::make_nvp("frame_size", frame_size);
        }
    };

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, mre::parameters const& params);

    namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

    struct package {
        friend class boost::serialization::access;

        struct tags {
            struct id {};
            struct content {};
            struct angle {};
            struct frozen {};
        };

        using container = bmi::multi_index_container<
            mre::content,
            bmi::indexed_by<
                bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::identity<mre::content>>,
                bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<tags::id>,          bmi::key<&mre::content::id>>,
                bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<tags::content>, bmi::key<&mre::content::hash>>,
                bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<tags::angle>,   bmi::key< &mre::content::angle>>,
                bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<tags::frozen>,  bmi::key<&mre::content::frozen_key>>>>;

        inline explicit package(mre::parameters const& params) : _loaded(false), _parameters(params) {}
        inline explicit package() : _loaded(false) {}
        void                          save(std::string const& filename) const;
        void                          load(std::string const& filename);
        inline std::size_t            size() const { return _samples.size(); }
        inline bool                   loaded() const { return _loaded; }
        mre::content const&           operator[](std::string const& id) const;
        mre::parameters const&        params() const { return _parameters; }
        template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned) {
            ar& boost::serialization::make_nvp("samples", _samples);
            ar& boost::serialization::make_nvp("params", _parameters);
        }

      public:
        std::size_t generate(std::size_t contents, std::size_t angles, size_t seed);
        std::size_t generate(std::size_t contents, std::size_t angles) {
            return generate(contents, angles, std::random_device{}());
        }

      private:
        bool            _loaded;
        container       _samples;
        mre::parameters _parameters;
    };

} // namespace mre

// { sources

std::ostream& mre::operator<<(std::ostream& stream, mre::parameters const& params) {
    stream << "params {" << std::endl;
    stream << "    degree:     " << params.degree << std::endl;
    stream << "    frame_size: " << params.frame_size << std::endl;
    stream << "}";
    return stream;
}

void mre::package::save(std::string const& filename) const {
    std::ofstream stream(filename, std::ios::binary);
    try {
        OA out(stream, FLAGS);
        std::cout << "serialization library version: " << out.get_library_version() << std::endl;
        out << *this;
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "Error saving archive: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    stream.close();
}

void mre::package::load(std::string const& filename) {
    std::ifstream stream(filename, std::ios::binary);
    try {
        IA in(stream, FLAGS);
        std::cout << "deserialization library version: " << in.get_library_version() << std::endl;
        in >> *this;
        _loaded = true;
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "Error loading archive: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    stream.close();
}

std::size_t mre::package::generate(std::size_t contents, std::size_t angles, size_t seed) {
    std::size_t count     = 0;
    std::size_t v_content = 0;
    while (v_content++ < contents) {
        mre::content x       = mre::content::generate(seed);
        std::size_t  v_angle = 0;
        while (v_angle++ < angles) {
            mre::content x_angle = x;
            x_angle.reset_angle_random(seed); // commenting out this line makes it work
            if (_samples.insert(x_angle).second)
                ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Boost " << BOOST_VERSION << "\n";
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << std::endl
                  << argv[0] << " pack FILENAME N" << std::endl
                  << argv[0] << " unpack FILENAME" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (argv[1] == std::string("pack")) {
        auto         params = mre::parameters{.degree = 4, .frame_size = 128};
        mre::package package(params);
        std::size_t  count = package.generate(boost::lexical_cast<std::size_t>(argv[3]), 4, 0xcafebabe);
        package.save(argv[2]);
        std::cout << "serialized: " << count << " contents" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    } else if (argv[1] == std::string("unpack")) {
        mre::package package;
        package.load(argv[2]);
        if (package.loaded()) {
            std::cout << "Package loaded: " << package.size() << std::endl << package.params() << std::endl;
            package.save("roundtrip");
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << std::endl
                  << argv[0] << " pack FILENAME N" << std::endl
                  << argv[0] << " unpack FILENAME" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

PS: Come to think of it that still leaves other indexes (like `tags::id`) that suffer from the hash-used-as-key problem. I don't think the data structure is sound [beyond using a non-unique non-deterministic hash as a unique key already observed]. E.g. the primary (`identity<>`-based) index is effectively the same as the one by `id()` in your original code, because `operator()` literally projects `std::less` over `id()`. That's

Here's a counter-gambit:

```
 // bool operator<(content  const& other) const { return idkey() <  other.idkey(); }
    bool operator==(content const& other) const { return idkey() == other.idkey(); }
```

With

```
    using container = bmi::multi_index_container<
        mre::content,
        bmi::indexed_by<
            bmi::hashed_unique<bmi::identity<mre::content>>,
            bmi::ordered_unique<bmi::tag<tags::id>,          bmi::key<&mre::content::id>>,
            bmi::hashed_unique<bmi::tag<tags::content>,      bmi::key<&mre::content::key>>,
            bmi::ordered_non_unique<bmi::tag<tags::angle>,   bmi::key<&mre::content::angle>>,
            bmi::hashed_non_unique<bmi::tag<tags::frozen>,   bmi::key<&mre::content::frozen_key>>>>;
```

(Full listing [Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/902ecc4ffeb81db6))

### TL;DR

Basically, don't use non-perfect hashes as keys. Additionally, don't rely on determinism of the algorithm, except with published cryptographical digests.

Comment: Added a PS <padding/>

Comment: Practically it is not just _length and _angle. Each content contains multiple vectors. It is not even the content only. There are style parameters. If I use `bmi::key` then the key will be as big as the content itself. That's why I used hashing. Such big key size will increase the size of the archive by more than double. Also those keys are tuples. There will not be any easy way to query them. If I have same hash for same content then I can query by that hash id. So, this solution is difficult to use in practical scenario.

Comment: "Using hashing" is fine. IFF used like in my PS.: as an actual hash for the hash-table. I didn't actually suggest a solution, just fixing the error. Also, I'd like to suggest composite-keys, which might in fact give you 80% of all the indexes in a single one when tuned right (composite keys can actually be queried by _partial_ tuples of leading key elements, which is [crazy powerful for ordered indices](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a85371%20composite_key&searchOn=3)). Keep in mind that the c++17 `key<>` extractor makes composite-key index specification a breeze. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that you're violating the requirements on loading time with respect to so-called [predicate serialization compatibility](https://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/multi_index_container.html#serialization):

> Given a binary predicate `Pred` over (`T`, `T`), and objects `p` and `q` of type `Pred`, we say that `q` is serialization-compatible with `p`  if:
>
> `p(x,y) == q(x',y')`
>
> for every `x` and `y` of type `T` and `x'` and `y'` being restored copies of `x` and `y`, respectively.

As applies to ordered indices, the requirement is that `value_comp()` at saving time be compatible with `value_comp` at loading time, that is, both behave the same for equivalent pairs of elements, `value_comp(x,y)` being defined as `pred(key(x),key(y)`, where `pred` is the less-than comparator (`std::less<...>` in your case) and `key` is the key extractor you provide for each index. As these key extractors depend on the implementation of `boost::hash`, and this has changed from Boost 1.74 to Boost 1.83, the requirement is violated and the loading code can't make sense of what it's retrieving, hence the exception.

If you want to know what's happening inside, let's look closer at the problem --this is only provided for the very curious, really, as it goes into the private implementation of Boost.MultiIndex. Your container is defined as:

```
using container = multi_index_container<
    mre::content,
    indexed_by<
        ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<mre::content>>,
        ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<tags::id>, const_mem_fun<mre::content, std::string, &mre::content::id>>,
        ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<tags::content>, const_mem_fun<mre::content, std::size_t, &mre::content::hash>>,
        ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<tags::angle>, const_mem_fun<mre::content, mre::content::angle_type, &mre::content::angle>>,
        ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<tags::frozen>, const_mem_fun<mre::content, std::size_t, &mre::content::frozen_id>>
    >
>;
```

where indices #0, #1, #2 and #4 depend directly or indirectly on `boost::hash` and are then violating the requirements. Additionally, the serialization code for `mre::comment`:

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("degree",     degree);
    ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("frame_size", frame_size);
}
```

does not save any info dependent on `boost::hash` (which is calculated on the fly, so to say). Now, the internal serialization algorithm of Boost.MultiIndex goes like this:

- Save

  - Save the elements following the order of index of index #0
  - For *non-unique* indices, locate the groups of equivalent elements (same key for that index) and save their relative order within the group, *using the element immediately preceding the group as an "anchor"*.
- Load

  - Load the elements and insert them into the container using index #0.
  - For *non_unique* elements: equivalent elements will we grouped together, but there's no guarantee their relative order is preserved, so restore it using the info stored at saving time.

It's the last step that causes the problem, and in particular within index #4 (the one based on `mre::content::frozen_id`). Note that your code generates many elements with the same `frozen_id()`, as this function only depends on `_length`:

```
std::size_t mre::package::generate(std::size_t contents, std::size_t angles){
    std::size_t count = 0;
    std::size_t v_content = 0;
    while(v_content++ < contents){
        mre::content x = mre::content::generate();
        std::size_t v_angle = 0;
        while(v_angle++ < angles){
            mre::content x_angle = x;
            x_angle.reset_angle_random(); // commenting out this line makes it work
            _samples.insert(x_angle);
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

So, on saving time you may end up with a bunch of elements with the same `frozen_id()` generated with Boost 1.74, for instance:

```
10387073523272624522 15299377970727330730 15299377970727330730 15299377970727330730...
```

that then will be loaded as a bunch of elements with different ids (because you're using Boost 1.83):

```
840800904510971812 9310016153812194557 9310016153812194557 9310016153812194557...
```

and now the problem goes like this: when trying to restore the order of 9310016153812194557s, we use as anchor (the preceding element) the element that was saved with id 10387073523272624522, but this will have now a different id and, almost certainly, will **not** be the one preceding this group at loading time. If you followed me so far, this is the problem you're encountering (the short explanation is you're violating the requirements of the library, of course).

Now, moving forward you should pay attention to @sehe's answer on how to do serialization without dependencies on functions without a fixed implementation. But I understand you have this code in production and you really need to load these legacy archives. You can hack your way using any of the following:

**Solution 1:** By the time the exception is thrown, elements are already loaded in the container, so you can catch and continue. **Updated 2024/03/06:** This unfortunately won't work in your case, as `_samples` serialization goes before that of `_parameters`, so if an exception is thrown when loading the former, the latter won't be loaded at all.

**Solution 2:** You can load the contents into an intermediate container without the problems on the last index we've described --this is wildly unspecified, mind you, but it should work. You should use it **ONLY** to handle legacy archives, moving forward do as @sehe says.

**<kbd>[Live Coliru Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98e7d2a8fa4a3774)</kbd>**

```
struct null_key_extractor
{
    using result_type = int;
    
    template<typename T>
    int operator()(const T&) const { return 0; }
};

struct package{
    ...
    
    using container = ...;
    
    using loading_container = boost::multi_index_container<
        mre::content,
        boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
            boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<mre::content>>,
            boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<tags::id>, boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<mre::content, std::string, &mre::content::id>>,
            boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<tags::content>, boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<mre::content, std::size_t, &mre::content::hash>>,
            boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<tags::angle>, boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<mre::content, mre::content::angle_type, &mre::content::angle>>,
            boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<null_key_extractor>
        >
    >;

    ...        

    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()

    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const {
        ar << boost::serialization::make_nvp("samples", _samples);
        ar << boost::serialization::make_nvp("params",  _parameters);
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        loading_container samples;
        ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("samples", samples);
        _samples.clear();
        _samples.insert(samples.begin(), samples.end());    
        ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("params",  _parameters);
    }

  ...
};
```

Comment: So, it seems the best solution is to have fir long term is a consistent portable hash function e.g. crc32, md5 etc.. or serialize the hash too.

Comment: None of the proposed solution worked. Please check the updated main.cpp (solution 2) in the repo. Solution 1 doesn't work because the _parameters is is gibberish after ignoring exception and deserializing.

Comment: Yes, solution 1 won't work because `_samples` is serialized before `_parameters`, so when a loading exception is thrown for the former the latter is not updated. Sorry about that. As for solution 2, you haven't translated it properly to your repo: note that it is a different `loading_container` `typedef` I'm using for loading, whereas you're still using `container`.